# SAS/SQL - Identifying/grouping return journeys in rail journey data

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table in Oracle that contains rail journeys. Some journeys have a journey_type of 'S', which means they are single journeys. However, some customers essentially use these single journeys to make a return journey (e.g. purchasing a single from London to Manchester and a single ticket from Manchester to London). I need to be able to identify instances of this and somehow group the two journeys into one row. To complicate matters a little further, 'reason for travel' is recorded at the transaction level and the two journeys will probably have different transaction IDs - so I need to be able to retain both of the values for this variable in the new row. I've been struggling with this today and haven't been able to come up with an acceptable solution so thought I'd ask for advice here.

Here is example data:

```
Cust_ID Journey_ID  Origin     Destination  Type    Date        Reason
100     100001      London       Manchester S       15/01/2014  Family
100     100100      Manchester   London     S       16/01/2014  Family
100     110023      London       Manchester S       25/01/2014  Family
100     114000      Manchester   London     S       29/01/2014  Holiday
100     129345      London       Norwich    S       02/02/2014  Business
100     134578      Norwich      London     S       15/02/2014  Business
100     145843      London       Manchester S       01/03/2014  Family
100     147893      Manchester   London     S       04/03/2014  Family
200     157878      Birmingham   London     S       04/04/2014  Friends
200     159899      London       Birmingham S       06/04/2014  Friends
```

I'd like to create something like this:

```
Cust_ID Journey_ID  Origin    Destination   Date            Reason1      Reason2
100     100001      London    Manchester    15/01/2014      Family       Family
100     110023      London    Manchester    25/01/2014      Family       Holiday
100     129345      London    Norwich       02/02/2014      Business     Business
100     145843      London    Manchester    01/03/2014      Family       Family
200     157878      Birmingham    London    04/04/2014      Friends      Friends
```

The tools I have available are Oracle SQL Developer and SAS. Any thoughts on how you'd go about this would be appreciated! The table contains many millions of records so efficiency is an issue.

edit: forgot to include transaction_id in the tables. It could either be the same or different  for the outward and return journeys.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution, although there may be a better way using HASH tables.  Essentially my appoach is to first change the transaction id for the return journey to be the same as the outbound journey, then it is a fairly simple matter of outputting the desired result.  If you need to keep the original transaction id for the return journey then you'll have to output the data to a new dataset instead of using MODIFY and then add in the other journeys of type 'R'.  I've added in a few extra data lines, including a couple of return journeys (one that occurs between 2 singles) and a single journey with no return.  Hope this helps.

```
/* create dummy dataset */
data have;
input Cust_ID Journey_ID Origin $ :12. Destination $ :12. Type $ Date :ddmmyy10. Reason $ Trans_id;
format date date9.;
datalines;
100     100001      London       Manchester S       15/01/2014  Family      1
100     100100      Manchester   London     S       16/01/2014  Family      2
100     110023      London       Manchester S       25/01/2014  Family      3
100     114000      Manchester   London     S       29/01/2014  Holiday     4
100     100300      London       Exeter     R       31/01/2014  Business    5
100     100300      Exeter       London     R       01/02/2014  Business    5
100     129345      London       Norwich    S       02/02/2014  Business    6
100     130300      Norwich      Ipswich    R       11/02/2014  Business    7
100     130300      Ipswich      Norwich    R       12/02/2014  Business    7
100     134578      Norwich      London     S       15/02/2014  Business    8
100     145843      London       Manchester S       01/03/2014  Family      9
100     147893      Manchester   London     S       04/03/2014  Family      10
100     148123      London       Brighton   S       06/03/2014  Family      11
200     157878      Birmingham   London     S       04/04/2014  Friends     12
200     159899      London       Birmingham S       06/04/2014  Friends     13
;
run;

/* sort data */
proc sort data=have;
by cust_id date trans_id;
run;

/* update transaction id for return journey to be same as outbound journey */
data have;
/* dataset entered twice to enable BY group processing */
modify have (where=(type='S')) have (where=(type='S')); 
by cust_id date trans_id;
retain _tid _orig _dest _pair;
if first.cust_id or _pair=1 then do;
        _tid = trans_id;
        _orig = origin;
        _dest = destination;
        _pair=0;
end;
/* does destination and origin match origin and destination of previous journey */
else if origin=_dest and destination=_orig then do;
    trans_id = _tid;
    _pair=1;
end;
run;

/* need to sort again as some trans_id's have changed */
proc sort data=have;
by cust_id trans_id descending date;
run;

/* output required data with both reason */
data want (keep=cust_id journey_id origin destination type date reason1 reason2);
set have;
by cust_id trans_id descending date;
length reason1 reason2 $12;
retain reason2;
if first.trans_id and not last.trans_id then reason2 = reason;
else if last.trans_id then do;
    reason1 = reason;
    output;
    call missing(reason1,reason2);
end;
run;
```